# How to access application resource file outside war file in struts2 application

Tags: struts2, web, struts

Currently i am doing a project so that i need to access application resource file
outside  from my war file.

So i that application resource file can be kept anywhere in my system and i can access it.

Comment: Struts 2 can't help regarding this it will look for the resource bundle in the following order.

Answer (score 0):

Resource bundle is searched in the following order:

```
ActionClass.properties
Interface.properties
BaseClass.properties
ModelDriven’s model
package.properties
Search up the i18n message key hierarchy itself
Global resource properties
```

Comment: Can i keep it OutSide of the war file??

Answer (score 0):

Go to following link, which shows way to load resource bundle for languages.
http://theswarmintelligence.blogspot.com/2012/08/use-resource-bundle-messages-files-out.html